# ERROR while loading & reading custom 20newsgroups corpus with NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am trying to load the **20newsgroups** corpus with the NLTK corpus reader and thereafter I am extracting words from all documents and tagging them. But it is showing error when I am trying to build the word extracted and tagged list.

Here is the **CODE**:

```
import nltk
import random

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

newsgroups = nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(
    r"C:\nltk_data\corpora\20newsgroups",
    r'(?!\.).*\.txt', 
    cat_pattern=r'(not_sports|sports)/.*',
    encoding="utf8")

documents = [(list(newsgroups.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in newsgroups.categories()
             for fileid in newsgroups.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)
```

And the corresponding **ERROR** is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-de2a1a6859ea> in <module>()
      1 documents = [(list(newsgroups.words(fileid)), category)
----> 2              for category in newsgroups.categories()
      3              for fileid in newsgroups.fileids(category)]
      4 
      5 random.shuffle(documents)

<ipython-input-10-de2a1a6859ea> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 documents = [(list(newsgroups.words(fileid)), category)
      2              for category in newsgroups.categories()
----> 3              for fileid in newsgroups.fileids(category)]
      4 
      5 random.shuffle(documents)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py in __len__(self)
    231             # iterate_from() sets self._len when it reaches the end
    232             # of the file:
--> 233             for tok in self.iterate_from(self._toknum[-1]): pass
    234         return self._len
    235 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    294             self._current_toknum = toknum
    295             self._current_blocknum = block_index
--> 296             tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
    297             assert isinstance(tokens, (tuple, list, AbstractLazySequence)), (
    298                 'block reader %s() should return list or tuple.' %

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py in _read_word_block(self, stream)
    120         words = []
    121         for i in range(20): # Read 20 lines at a time.
--> 122             words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
    123         return words
    124 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in readline(self, size)
   1166         while True:
   1167             startpos = self.stream.tell() - len(self.bytebuffer)
-> 1168             new_chars = self._read(readsize)
   1169 
   1170             # If we're at a '\r', then read one extra character, since

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in _read(self, size)
   1398 
   1399         # Decode the bytes into unicode characters
-> 1400         chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
   1401 
   1402         # If we got bytes but couldn't decode any, then read further.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in _incr_decode(self, bytes)
   1429         while True:
   1430             try:
-> 1431                 return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
   1432             except UnicodeDecodeError as exc:
   1433                 # If the exception occurs at the end of the string,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_8.py in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

I have tried changing the encoding in the corpus reader to **ascii** and **utf16** as well. That's not working either. I am not sure whether the regex I have provided is the right one or not. The filenames in the 20newsgroups corpus are in the form of 2 numbers separated by a hyphen(-), such as:

> 5-53286
>
> 102-53553
>
> 8642-104983

The second thing that I am worried about is whether the error is being generated from the document contents when they are being read for feature extraction.
Here are a what documents in 20newsgroups corpus look like:

> From: bil@okcforum.osrhe.edu (Bill Conner) Subject: Re: free moral
>   agency
>
> dean.kaflowitz (decay@cbnewsj.cb.att.com) wrote: : >  : > I think
>   you're letting atheist mythology
>
> : Great start.  I realize immediately that you are not interested : in
>   discussion and are going to thump your babble at me.  I would : much
>   prefer an answer from Ms Healy, who seems to have a : reasonable and
>   reasoned approach to things.  Say, aren't you the : creationist guy
>   who made a lot of silly statements about : evolution some time ago?
>
> : Duh, gee, then we must be talking Christian mythology now.  I : was
>   hoping to discuss something with a reasonable, logical : person, but
>   all you seem to have for your side is a repetition : of the same
>   boring mythology I've seen a thousand times before. : I am deleting
>   the rest of your remarks, unless I spot something : that approaches an
>   answer, because they are merely a repetition : of some uninteresting
>   doctrine or other and contain no thought : at all.
>
> : I have to congratulate you, though, Bill.  You wouldn't : know a
>   logical argument if it bit you on the balls.  Such : a persistent lack
>   of function in the face of repeated : attempts to assist you in
>   learning (which I have seen : in this forum and others in the past)
>   speaks of a talent : that goes well beyond my own, meager abilities. 
>   I just don't : seem to have that capacity for ignoring outside
>   influences.
>
> : Dean Kaflowitz
>
> Dean,
>
> Re-read your comments, do you think that merely characterizing an
>   argument is the same as refuting it? Do you think that ad hominum
>   attacks are sufficient to make any point other than you disapproval of
>   me? Do you have any contribution to make at all?
>
> Bill

```
From: cmk@athena.mit.edu (Charles M Kozierok) Subject: Re: Jack Morris

In article <1993Apr19.024222.11181@newshub.ariel.yorku.ca> cs902043@ariel.yorku.ca (SHAWN LUDDINGTON) writes: } In article <1993Apr18.032345.5178@cs.cornell.edu> tedward@cs.cornell.edu (Edward [Ted] Fischer) writes: } >In article <1993Apr18.030412.1210@mnemosyne.cs.du.edu> gspira@nyx.cs.du.edu (Greg Spira) writes: } >>Howard_Wong@mindlink.bc.ca (Howard Wong) writes: }
>> } >>>Has Jack lost a bit of his edge? What is the worst start Jack Morris has had? } >> } >>Uh, Jack lost his edge about 5 years ago, and has had only one above } >>average year in the last 5. } > } >Again goes to prove that it is better to be good than lucky.  You can }
>count on good tomorrow.  Lucky seems to be prone to bad starts (and a } >bad finish last year :-). } > } >(Yes, I am enjoying every last run he gives up.  Who was it who said } >Morris was a better signing than Viola?) }  } Hey Valentine, I don't see Boston with any world series rings on their } fingers.

oooooo. cheap shot. :^)

} Damn, Morris now has three and probably the Hall of Fame in his  } future.

who cares? he had two of them before he came to Toronto; and if the Jays had signed Viola instead of Morris, it would have been Frank who won 20 and got the ring. and he would be on his way to 20 this year, too.

} Therefore, I would have to say Toronto easily made the best  } signing.

your logic is curious, and spurious.

there is no reason to believe that Viola wouldn't have won as many games had *he* signed with Toronto. when you compare their stupid W-L records, be sure to compare their team's offensive averages too.


now, looking at anything like the Morris-Viola sweepstakes a year later is basically hindsight. but there were plenty of reasons why it should have been apparent that Viola was the better pitcher, based on previous recent years and also based on age (Frank is almost 5 years younger! how many knew that?). people got caught up in the '91 World Series, and then on Morris' 21 wins last year. wins are the stupidest, most misleading statistic in baseball, far worse than RBI or R. that he won 21 just means that the Jays got him a lot of runs.

the only really valid retort to Valentine is: weren't the Red Sox trying to get Morris too? oh, sure, they *said* Viola was their first choice afterwards, but what should we have expected they would say?

} And don't tell me Boston will win this year.  They won't  } even be in the top 4 in the division, more like 6th.

if this is true, it won't be for lack of contribution by Viola, so who cares?

-*- charles
```

Please suggest me whether the error is while loading the documents or while reading the files and extracting words. What do I need to do to load the corpus correctly?

Answer (score 0):

NLTK has corpora loading issues

you can load the useful category data using

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
cats = ['alt.atheism', 'sci.space']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=cats)
```

Where newsgroups_train.target_names give you categories.

Comment: I was aware of this. This is more like the last resort that I do not wish to undertake. I want to do it using NLTK somehow, if possible by using the corpus reader or by some other method replicating the same. In particular, I want help regarding why this nasty error shows up. I have tried many things but to no avail. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: And can you help me with another thing? How do I merge the documents into two categories and import them into one category using scikit-learn? In the answer you have provided, I want to merge all the documents in 'alt.atheism' and 'sci.space' into a custom category, say 'generic_news'. It doesn't matter if it is done during fetching the docs or after. It should be such that it doesn't affect the execution of rest of the code.